# Why are there pairs of wind instruments in a symphonic orchestra?

Tags: theory, orchestra, performance-practice

Why is it so that there are often two identical oboes, two identical clarinets, two identical bassoons and two identical trombones in a symphonic orchestra?

Is it just because one instrument is not loud enough and both are always playing exactly the same line? Or does each one of the pair play different lines?

Comment: Is your question about number of players per part comparing winds to strings? Pairs for the winds, but many more players for the strings.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - My knowledge about symphonic orchestra is rather limited. Somebody told me in the past that many violins in an orchestra is solely for the sake of volume. So, I just wanted to find out if it was also the case with the winds.

Comment: Probably would be better worded as "what is the history behind the makeup of a "standard"  symphonic orchestra?"

Comment: Tradition plays a big part.  Just like the String Quartet is a standard, but there are pieces written with a second cello added, or a bass added.   Random works exist for mixed string-wind sextets and octets, and so on but the quartet and the trio (violin , cello, piano)  are far more common.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both. When they play in unison it’s louder. When they play separate lines it’s a richer sound. There’s also usually two flutes, two trumpets, and four French horns.

And I think the word “identical” might be overstating it. Yes, generally the second chair will be asked or expected to play the same or similar make and model of instrument, but no two instruments or players are identical. Having the slightly different tone between the two instruments adds to the richness of the orchestra.

It’s similar to there being two violin sections. And 6-10 violins in each section. They can play together or divisi or one can play solo, etc.

The overall size of the orchestra is to fill the concert hall so everyone can hear in a time before electronic amplification. The relative numbers of instruments create a mostly balanced level across the orchestra, at least within reason.

Studying scores while listening carefully to symphonic works will help make this all clearer. Also going to see live symphonic music would give you a first hand understanding.

Comment: It would be interesting to also explain why there aren't more than two (typically). Two is richer than one, but then why not twelve (as the norm)?

Comment: @Aaron I’m sure a lot of orchestras today have a permanent staff sufficient for the majority of romantic and classical works and then on-call lists for special situations. As to why there was no significant orchestral “arms race” between 1780 and 1830 or so, I don’t know. There are situations where there **are** more than two, but for reasons I don’t really know, Beethoven and Mozart and Brahms all wrote for similar sizes and compositions of orchestras and many popular works can be okayed by fairly similar ensembles.

Comment: @Aaron If I’m reading the Wikipedia article right, the popularity of pairs of winds and brass comes from Beethoven’s specifications for his symphonies. It claims that the standard of four horns comes from his ninth symphony. I can only guess that the romantic composers often used the Beethoven orchestra as their starting point. Certainly by the 20th century things got much more eclectic (e.g., Ravel’s Bolero). And for those who don’t know, three of each wind and brass and 6-8 horns is common in film scoring orchestras today.

Comment: That seems a worthy add to the main post, at least under the label of educated guess. It certainly a strong hypothesis that, given the Romantic composers' reverence for Beethoven, they would go with his orchestration.

Comment: @Aaron beginning in the mid to late 19th century it was common to have three or more instruments of each woodwind family; the first piece I looked at as a quick sanity check was Parsifal.  Todd, as to the fashion for pairs arising with Beethoven, that can't be right. Look at Mozart's and Haydn's symphonies and at late baroque orchestral works.  They often have winds in pairs.  Even the standard woodwind choir of pairs of flutes, oboes, clarinets, and bassoons predates Beethoven -- See Haydn's London symphonies, written before Beethoven was 5.

Comment: @phoog Yeah I was paraphrasing Wikipedia. Perhaps the point that the Wikipedia editor was trying to make is why people didn’t go beyond pairs (and four horns) for most of the 19th century?

Comment: No.   The two parts (or 3 or four for trombones, French Horns)  are very rarely if ever the same.

Comment: I cannot believe this answer is voted up so highly when it's almost 100% wrong.  I challenge anyone out there to identify the difference in tone between a Selmer and a Buffet clarinet  (unless radically different mouthpieces are used).      It's easy for a trumpet or French horn, or clarinet  to play over {the entire violin section playing forte} .     Volume balance comes from everyone adjusting their sound level so the music as a whole has the desired balance among all themes & backgrounds written in the score.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The requirement to follow the leader on clarinet brand is more political than tonal, from what I understand. That said, I stand by the assertion that no two players sound identical no matter what instruments they use. They will sound identical enough to the audience, and perhaps that's what the asker is getting at, and maybe that's the point you're making. My own (admittedly narrow) literature review suggests that your comment about "the two parts are very rarely if ever the same" doesn't hold up. Or maybe we're saying different things.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft In every symphony that I've reviewed, there are unison passages and non-unison passages for pretty much every wind and brass pair/group except for horns, where rarely do all four horns play unison (although it does happen). So you're right that the entire *parts* are never identical, but there **are** many unison passages. And of course the final balance of the orchestra is created by the playing, not the instrumentation. Also keep in mind that this answer is pitched to the apparent level of understanding of the asker, so I've over simplified many concepts.

Comment: @ToddWilcox  I didn't make any claim about the actual choice of maker in an orchestral setting. Just wanted to state that  any difference in tone is due to mouthpiece and player, not the instrument.  But I doubt there's any such thing going on , seeing as the violin section will have axes from 50 different makers (for 12 players :-) ).   If one trombonist wants a  copper bell I would be shocked if the section or the director disallowed that.

Comment: Remember that symphonies are a small part of a symphone orchestra's repertoire.  Having put in many years as a clarinetist (and a bunch more as cellist) I can say that overall unison is not that common.  Parallel thirds or other harmonic matching lines, yes.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I've never sat in a professional orchestra as a wind player, but I've read multiple accounts from pros saying they were asked to follow the leader on make. This makes a lot more sense in horns where the wrap can make a clear difference in tone, but I've been told it can apply with woodwinds also. FWIW, I'm also a bit surprised this is currently the highest voted answer. I didn't put a lot of thought or research into it.

Answer (score 6):

Much (?) more frequently they play different voices; note, that as for all wind instruments only one tone can be produced at the same time. So if the composer desires an additional tone of that same color, there is no choice but to add another player.
The first position typically has a bit more to play, especially in pianissimo he/she may play alone.

(For super-difficult passages the conductor may even instruct the player of second instrument to stay silent in unison passages, since differences are far easier to spot than wrong notes. This, as correctly commented, is no issue for professional orchestras, but applies to student and amateur ensembles.)

Comment: "since differences are far easier to spot than wrong notes" - Can you, please, elaborate on this sentence?

Comment: @brilliant  I agree with you.  What he should have written is that two identical instruments in unison will sound worse when slightly out of tune than two instruments (in unison) from different sections of the orchestra.

Comment: @brilliant One errant note may not be noticed by people unfamiliar with the piece, a wrong note/rhythm may fit into the context of the music and not sound obviously wrong. But if two players playing the exact same line suddenly play something different, it's more obvious that one of them is wrong.

Comment: I suspect your last point may be more true in student ensembles. I would expect this to be less of a problem with professional musicians.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is you have enough players per instrument to cover the number of written parts, except for the string which used large numbers of players, not because there were many more written parts, but for the special *timbral* quality of a large group of strings.

Lots of classical symphonies have just two parts per wind instruments. Two parts meaning two notes to be played simultaneously. So just two players was enough to handle to two written parts.

Strings were different. Especially the violins. Lots of violins were used. Not because there were many more written parts, not for volume, but for timbre. The group sound is "richer", "warmer", also the bow attack become a little softer, more diffused. However you describe it a large group of strings sounds timbrally different that just one string player per part.

You can also think of it in terms of instrumental genres too. The symphonic orchestra is essentially a *string* orchestra and the winds just augment that string orchestra for timbral color. The large group of strings distinguishes the symphony orchestra from instrumental groupings like a concertino group in a concerto or chamber ensembles like a string quartet. So, many strings versus single string players distinguishes some genres, but the number of wind players doesn't. You only need the number of wind players to fit the number of wind parts.

In my mind that makes the distinguishing factor about how many players per instrument to be mostly about the timbral expectations of various instrumental genres.

Comment: How true -- since a "wind ensemble" aka "concert band"  might have 6 flutes, 6 to 12 clarinets,  and yet only one or two tubas, one bari sax,   and so on.   3 trumpets plus 3 cornets

Comment: This is also why a solo violin sounds different from the ensemble. A great example of this is the first allegro from Vivaldi's _La primavera_, which alternates between duet violins and tutti sections. In a good recording, you can really notice the difference in timbre.

Answer (score 2):

Reed instruments have keyed pitches.  As opposed to bowed strings (and incidentally, trombones) that means that to a certain degree the pitch relations between instruments with purportedly identical pitch are mostly fixed, but since expressiveness and volume typically impacts pitch as well, expressive melody lines don't add up to a rich complex texture like with violins (also aided by a comparatively rich overtone spectrum) but contain some non-organic semi-systematic beatings.  At the same time, any multiplication of instruments diminishes expressivity by averaging it out.

2 is a compromise that still provides redundancy (and differentiation from a solo voice, even though orchestral woodwinds are all expected to be able to carry a solo, something not to equal degree the case with strings) while not attempting to compose a complex sound texture which does not work all as convincingly with reed instruments as with some others.

I am fuzzy about trombones.